# Django - Boolean updated on web view but not when exported

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

Depending on certain conditions on the models.py, I would like to have the ABC BooleanField to be ticked (green check) or unticked (red cross). This, I have done it without any problems; however, when I am trying to export (as a CSV or XLSX) that same dataset with the ABC BooleanField, the BooleanField is not updated according to the web view nor the models.py I have set. Could you please give me some guidance? The following are parts of the code:

```
class something(models.Model)
    book = models.BooleanField(default=False)


... some code ...

    def bookcheck(self):
        if self.writingDate is not None:
            if self.publishDate is not None:
                self.book = True
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    bookcheck.boolean = True
```

Comment: You're not saving the model. `self.save()` after you've made the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save after updating your model instance

```
if self.publishDate is not None:
    self.book = True
    self.save()
    return True
```

This will update the row in the database that corresponds to the object you are updating.

I do not think the following line of code will run

```
bookcheck.boolean = True
```

`bookcheck` is not defined here. `self.bookcheck` is, but even then, it is a function not a variable, and therefore it has no property that can be updated.

**Note:**

In Python, instead of

```
if self.writingDate is not None:
```

you can do

```
if self.writingDate:
```